# MVC4 FoolProof Data Annotations - How to check that field does not equal to zero?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I am trying to use MVC Foolproof library to validate my model and show error message respectively. However when I use Foolproof validation, on clicking the submit button even the regular validation is not showing.

My requirement is that I have a numeric textbox  and it should not be null or zero.The textbox value is calculated based on the value selected from the previous dropdownlist.

Below is the code for both fields in the model with data annotation,

```
using Foolproof;

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fee is not given", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [NotEqualTo("0",ErrorMessage="Duration cannot be zero")]
    public Nullable<int> Duration { get; set; }
```

Html Textbox

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MultiCourse.Duration,
        new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Course Duration", @id = "txtCourseDuration" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MultiCourse.Duration)
```

Bundle Config class

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/plugins/jQueryVal/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/plugins/jQueryVal/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/plugins/jQueryVal/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive*"));
```

Comment: What do you mean 'readonly'? What is the point of validation on a property which cannot be edited?

Comment: oops...sorry actually the textbox is not readonly.Updated the question..Kindly excuse.

Comment: Your misunderstanding the `[NotEqualTo]` attribute - it compares the value of the property with the value of another property.

Comment: If so is the case, how can I acheive the above scenario.Posting code will be helpful..

Comment: Can negative values be added? If not then a `[Range]` attribute would be easiest.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok.What will be the maximum value if we are using `[Range]`.In this case we cannot set a specific maximum value.

Comment: If the property is `int`, then just use `[Range(1, int.MaxValue)]`

Comment: Thanks mate..If you could post this as answer i could accept it..

Comment: @StephenMuecke if possible have a look @ this question [Resetting Jquery Select2 Multiple dropdownlist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119938/resetting-jquery-select2-multiple-dropdownlist-causes-a-blank-item-to-be-selecte)

Comment: Not familiar with Select2, but I'll check it out tomorrow :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foolproof `[NotEqualTo]` attribute compares the value of the property with the value of another property. In your case this would throw an exception because you model does not (and cant) contain a property named `0`.

If only positive values are allowed, then you could use a `[Range]` attribute

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Duration must be greater than zero")]
public Nullable<int> Duration { get; set; }
```

Alternatively if negative values were allowed, you could include a property in your view model (say) `int InvalidDuration` and use

```
[NotEqualTo("InvalidDuration", ErrorMessage="Duration cannot be zero")]
public Nullable<int> Duration { get; set; }
```

and include a hidden input in the view

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.InvalidDuration)
```