# Resetting Jquery Select2 Multiple dropdownlist causes a blank item to be selected?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-select2

I am using [Multiple Select2](https://select2.github.io/) plugin in an user registraion page.On clicking the submit button,after the details are saved i am resetting the dropdownlist.The problem is that when i select another item from the dropdownlist a `blank item` is automatically selected in the dropdownlist

[image]

**Html**

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MultipleCourseId
                        , Model.MultipleCourseList
                        , ""
                       , new { @class = "form-control select2", @id = "ddlCourseMultiple",@multiple="multiple" })
```

**Calling reset on Jquery Button click**

```
 $(document).on("click", "#btnCancel", clearAll);
//clear all controls
var clearAll = function () {
    $(".form-control").val('');
    //resetting dpdwn for clearing the selected option        
    $("#ddlCourseMultiple").select2("val", "");
    return false;
};
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like? It sounds like you might have a blank option, which isn't required for multiple select boxes.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.Question has been modified(included html of the select list)

Comment: Thanks your idea helped me . I used `ListBox` instead of dropdownlist which doesnot have blankoption and this saved me.If you could post the answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

You could try this :

```
$("#ddlCourseMultiple").val(null).trigger("change");
```